# jQuery on 'scroll' not working with selector

Tags: jquery

https://jsfiddle.net/bonbonlemon/3ug8aybh/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent">
    <span class="child"></span>
    <span class="child"></span>
    <span class="child"></span>
    <span class="child"></span>
    <span class="child"></span>
    <span class="child"></span>
    <span class="child"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.container').on('scroll', '.parent', function() {
    console.log('scroll');
});
```

The event will fire if I get rid of the selector param and just make it:

```
$('.parent').on('scroll', function() {
    console.log('scroll');
});
```

Why is that?

```js
$('.container').on('scroll', '.parent', function() {
    console.log('scroll');
});
```

```css
.parent {
  background: yellow;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.child {
  display: inline-block;
  background: blue;
  height: 90px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="parent">
    <span class="child"></span>
    <span class="child"></span>
    <span class="child"></span>
    <span class="child"></span>
    <span class="child"></span>
    <span class="child"></span>
    <span class="child"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The scroll event does not bubble: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll_event

Comment: @Terry Aha! That's good to know. But doesn't including `.parent` as the Selector param attach the scroll event directly onto the `.parent` element?

Comment: No. Your first snippet is event delegation that relies on an event bubbling from `.parent` up to `.container`, where it is captured. Since the scroll event never bubbles the snippet will never work.